# How Does uWSGI log-slow Behavior

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm using uWSGI for production service host pyramid app, here is my uWSGI config below:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8071
master = true
processes = 5
harakiri = 60
harakiri-verbose = true
limit-post = 65536
post-buffering = 8192
;disable-logging = true
logger = file:logfile=/opt/log/uwsgi.log,maxsize=209715200
req-logger = file:logfile=/opt/log/uwsgi-req.log,maxsize=209715200
pidfile = /opt/log/uwsgi.pid
listen = 127
max-requests = 1000
reload-on-rss = 96
no-orphans = true
log-slow = 3000
enable-threads = true
paste-logger = %p
buffer-size = 32768
```

As you see I have log all requests to `/opt/log/uwsgi-req.log`, log other logs to `/opt/log/uwsgi.log`, from what I observed, basically it acts just like no effect for `log-slow = 3000`, and I can't find any reference in the [documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#log-slow) for `log-slow` behavior. Actually I thought it should be log slow requests to `/opt/log/uwsgi.log` or somewhere else place so I can easily check slow requests.

So my question is can someone tell me how `log-slow` option behavior in uWSGI?